# how to generate the javascript code in blockly

Tags: blockly

I want to generate javascript for my blockly which does not have any input. I got the Javascript function from generator stub but it requires to assemble a javascript code into **var code** variable which I am not geting.
 i already tried this:

```
var code = Blockly.JavaScript.workspaceToCode(workspace);
```

But it shows me code is undefined.

and I am getting this error:

```
Cannot read property 'call' of undefined at Blockly.Generator.blockToCode (blockly_compressed.js:1572) at Blockly.Generator.workspaceToCode (blockly_compressed.js:1570)
```

Can you please help me out that how do I generate javascript code and assemble it?

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can generate JS code and run it:

```
  <script>
    var workspace = Blockly.inject('blocklyDiv',
        {media: '../../media/',
         toolbox: document.getElementById('toolbox')});
    Blockly.Xml.domToWorkspace(document.getElementById('startBlocks'),
                               workspace);

    // Generate JavaScript code and display it.
    function showCode() {
      Blockly.JavaScript.INFINITE_LOOP_TRAP = null;
      var code = Blockly.JavaScript.workspaceToCode(workspace);
      alert(code);
    }

    // Generate JavaScript code and run it.
    function runCode() {
      window.LoopTrap = 1000;
      Blockly.JavaScript.INFINITE_LOOP_TRAP =
          'if (--window.LoopTrap == 0) throw "Infinite loop.";\n';
      var code = Blockly.JavaScript.workspaceToCode(workspace);
      Blockly.JavaScript.INFINITE_LOOP_TRAP = null;
      try {
        eval(code);
      } catch (e) {
        alert(e);
      }
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
    at Blockly.Generator.blockToCode (blockly_compressed.js:1572)
    at Blockly.Generator.workspaceToCode (blockly_compressed.js:1570)

Comment: did you include all necessary .js files?

Comment: you add <script src="blockly_compressed.js"></script> in <head>, but the location of .js file is not correct. So, it cannot find it and "...blockToCode" &  "...workspaceToCode" cannot be executed!

Comment: No, It did not solve my problem yet. I put the blockly_compressed.js on the right location because it finds the path after clicking on it. Also, I am loading this file at the very start. But still I am getting the same error.